# How to group-filter field by values in a different field in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following data in BigQuery:

```
user  action
   1       0
   1       1
   2       0
   2       0
   3       1
   3       0
```

I would like to filter the users by those who have at least one action equal to 1, but keep every row for these users. So, the result should be this:

```
user  action
   1       0
   1       1
   3       1
   3       0
```

What I have done is the following. First, I `group by` user and create an array for the actions, filter for those that have the value 1 in the arrays (`table_2`), and then I `unnest`.

```
WITH table_1 AS (
    SELECT '1' AS user, '0' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS user, '1' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '2' AS user, '0' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '2' AS user, '0' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '3' AS user, '1' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '3' AS user, '0' AS action
),

table_2 AS (
    SELECT 
        user, 
        ARRAY_AGG(action) AS action_array
    FROM table_1
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING '1' IN UNNEST(action_array)
)

SELECT 
    user, 
    action_array 
FROM table_2, table_2.action_array
```

Is there a better/more efficient/more sophisticated way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the right way to do so

```
select *
from table_1
where true 
qualify countif(action = '1') over(partition by user) > 0
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
Select user, action
From table where user in (select user from table group by user having sum(action) <> 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to solve this.

Using a the qualify filter (Option 1) as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause) you have significant speed gains over the sub query (Option 2) style and as stated by @MikhailBerlyant it is the correct way to do so.

```
WITH table_1 AS (
    SELECT '1' AS user, '0' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS user, '1' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '2' AS user, '0' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '2' AS user, '0' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '3' AS user, '1' AS action
    UNION ALL SELECT '3' AS user, '0' AS action
)

-- Option 1
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE true 
QUALIFY COUNTIF(action = '1') OVER (PARTITION BY user) > 0    

-- Option 2
SELECT t1.* 
FROM (
    SELECT user, COUNTIF(action = '1') as has_action
    FROM table_1
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING has_action > 0
) as h1
JOIN table_1 as t1
    ON t1.user = h1.user
```